# Error 401 Authorization required when pushing to github repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I've been working with my remote github repository with no problem at all. But since yesterday I'm not able to push to my remote repository anymore.

I work with the eclipse IDE git pluggin and whenever I try to push I am getting this error:

> https://github.com/jotaseme/josemaria.moreno.IWVG-doo.miw.upm.es.git:
>   401 Authorization Required

I've double-checked the user and password and also I've tried with other pc. The same situation: failed pushing to remote repository.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I managed to get it working, but it is not a solution. The 401 message is a pop up window asking for my git user and password and despite of I was typing the correct credentials I was getting that 401 error again and again till I canceled and closed that popup and it worked. So all I have to do now is cancel that prompt and I can push to my repository. Now, I still don't know why is asking for my credential and specially why the correct credential isn't working. Anyway, I can push now so it's ok. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this gist in one of the eclipse platforms:

In Eclipse
Help -> Install New Software
Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.1a
Select the "EPP Marketplace Client"
Proceed with defaults